# How to put your GPS track in a video?

Tags: editing, video-recording, youtube

I am about to start a channel on YouTube.

There will be occasions that I will drive while recording my path with an indoor (inside car) camera.  I thought that it could be great if I put a tiny square on the corner of the video with the GPS tracking corresponding to my car path.

Is it possible? What do I need to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I personally use RaceRender, however, there is also DashWare.

Both can edit video and add GPS position overlays.

Bare in mind, neither of them can add the actual "map" like one from Google Maps, just a line showing your path and a marker showing the current location.

Again, my personal preference is to use RR or DW to produce a video with a magenta background so I can Chroma Key it in my editor (Magix Vegas).

I find the built-in editors in both programs a bit fiddly, so the use of a proper editor is recommended but they're fine if you just want to load a video, apply the overlay and render it out.

Answer (score 0):

If I was doing this for a video production, I would use After Effects, and import the GPX track from a GPS device into a mapping plugin like [GeoLayers](https://aescripts.com/geolayers/):

https://aescripts.com/learn/1-min-tut-use-geolayers-with-a-gpx-track/